# OpenGLWiget - Почему версия на OpenGL выглядит менее сглаженной, чем нативный рендер?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

Изучаю уроки и доку внутри Qt Creatora.

Понадобилось отрисовывать кучу 2D графики и решил заюзать аппаратное ускорение.

Нашел [простой пример](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtopengl-2dpainting-example.html), где все более чем понятно, но моего внутреннего перфекциониста гложет один вопрос: Почему версия на OpenGL выглядит на глаз куда менее сглаженной, чем нативный рендер?

И в довесок вопрос: использует ли нативный рендер гпу ускорение?

Спасибо!

Скрин и код доступны по ссылке, но вот (Слева кружочки ровнее!):

[image: Слева кружочки ровнее!]

P.S. Win10 x64, gtx 1050

Comment: нативный использует Win32 API, а что уж оно там использует не совсем понятно. Сглаживание OpenGL  подозреваю, что просто не включено см. `QGLFormat::setSamples(int numSamples)`

Comment: Нет, оно включено в main.cpp:

`QSurfaceFormat fmt;`

`fmt.setSamples(4);`

`QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(fmt);`

Comment: а надо ещё смотреть включилось сглаживание или нет, Default Format это же по сути рекомендация, а реальность зависит от карточки и настроек видео